# How to get the classes name on object detection tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

How to get the classes name of prediction?
the code (from https://tensorflow-object-detection-api-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/auto_examples/object_detection_camera.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-object-detection-camera-py)

```
import os

DATA_DIR = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'data')
MODELS_DIR = os.path.join(DATA_DIR, 'models')
for dir in [DATA_DIR, MODELS_DIR]:
    if not os.path.exists(dir):
        os.mkdir(dir)

import tarfile
import urllib.request

# Download and extract model
MODEL_DATE = '20200711'
MODEL_NAME = 'ssd_resnet101_v1_fpn_640x640_coco17_tpu-8'
MODEL_TAR_FILENAME = MODEL_NAME + '.tar.gz'
MODELS_DOWNLOAD_BASE = 'http://download.tensorflow.org/models/object_detection/tf2/'
MODEL_DOWNLOAD_LINK = MODELS_DOWNLOAD_BASE + MODEL_DATE + '/' + MODEL_TAR_FILENAME
PATH_TO_MODEL_TAR = os.path.join(MODELS_DIR, MODEL_TAR_FILENAME)
PATH_TO_CKPT = os.path.join(MODELS_DIR, os.path.join(MODEL_NAME, 'checkpoint/'))
PATH_TO_CFG = os.path.join(MODELS_DIR, os.path.join(MODEL_NAME, 'pipeline.config'))
if not os.path.exists(PATH_TO_CKPT):
    print('Downloading model. This may take a while... ', end='')
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(MODEL_DOWNLOAD_LINK, PATH_TO_MODEL_TAR)
    tar_file = tarfile.open(PATH_TO_MODEL_TAR)
    tar_file.extractall(MODELS_DIR)
    tar_file.close()
    os.remove(PATH_TO_MODEL_TAR)
    print('Done')

# Download labels file
LABEL_FILENAME = 'mscoco_label_map.pbtxt'
LABELS_DOWNLOAD_BASE = \
    'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tensorflow/models/master/research/object_detection/data/'
PATH_TO_LABELS = os.path.join(MODELS_DIR, os.path.join(MODEL_NAME, LABEL_FILENAME))
if not os.path.exists(PATH_TO_LABELS):
    print('Downloading label file... ', end='')
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(LABELS_DOWNLOAD_BASE + LABEL_FILENAME, PATH_TO_LABELS)
    print('Done')

os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '2'    # Suppress TensorFlow logging
import tensorflow as tf
from object_detection.utils import label_map_util
from object_detection.utils import config_util
from object_detection.utils import visualization_utils as viz_utils
from object_detection.builders import model_builder

tf.get_logger().setLevel('ERROR')           # Suppress TensorFlow logging (2)

# Enable GPU dynamic memory allocation
gpus = tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')
for gpu in gpus:
    tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(gpu, True)

# Load pipeline config and build a detection model
configs = config_util.get_configs_from_pipeline_file(PATH_TO_CFG)
model_config = configs['model']
detection_model = model_builder.build(model_config=model_config, is_training=False)

# Restore checkpoint
ckpt = tf.compat.v2.train.Checkpoint(model=detection_model)
ckpt.restore(os.path.join(PATH_TO_CKPT, 'ckpt-0')).expect_partial()

# Load pipeline config and build a detection model
configs = config_util.get_configs_from_pipeline_file(PATH_TO_CFG)
model_config = configs['model']
detection_model = model_builder.build(model_config=model_config, is_training=False)

# Restore checkpoint
ckpt = tf.compat.v2.train.Checkpoint(model=detection_model)
ckpt.restore(os.path.join(PATH_TO_CKPT, 'ckpt-0')).expect_partial()


def get_model_detection_function(model):
    @tf.function
    def detect_fn(image):
        """Detect objects in image."""
        image, shapes = model.preprocess(image)
        prediction_dict = model.predict(image, shapes)
        detections = model.postprocess(prediction_dict, shapes)
        
        return detections, prediction_dict, tf.reshape(shapes, [-1])

    return detect_fn

detect_fn = get_model_detection_function(detection_model)

category_index = label_map_util.create_category_index_from_labelmap(PATH_TO_LABELS,
                                                                    use_display_name=True)

import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

import numpy as np

while True:
    # Read frame from camera
    ret, image_np = cap.read()

    # Expand dimensions since the model expects images to have shape: [1, None, None, 3]
    image_np_expanded = np.expand_dims(image_np, axis=0)

    # Things to try:
    # Flip horizontally
    # image_np = np.fliplr(image_np).copy()

    # Convert image to grayscale
    # image_np = np.tile(
    #     np.mean(image_np, 2, keepdims=True), (1, 1, 3)).astype(np.uint8)

    input_tensor = tf.convert_to_tensor(np.expand_dims(image_np, 0), dtype=tf.float32)
    detections, predictions_dict, shapes = detect_fn(input_tensor)

    label_id_offset = 1
    image_np_with_detections = image_np.copy()

    viz_utils.visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array(
          image_np_with_detections,
          detections['detection_boxes'][0].numpy(),
          (detections['detection_classes'][0].numpy() + label_id_offset).astype(int),
          detections['detection_scores'][0].numpy(),
          category_index,
          use_normalized_coordinates=True,
          max_boxes_to_draw=200,
          min_score_thresh=.30,
          agnostic_mode=False)

    # Display output
    cv2.imshow('object detection', cv2.resize(image_np_with_detections, (800, 600)))

    if cv2.waitKey(25) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

actually the code is working fine but i want to get the class name to make some action..

for example :

```
if variable_name_class == 'cat':
    {action 1}
elif variable_name_class == 'dog':
    {action 2}
```

maybe to be like this

```
while True:
    # Read frame from camera
    ret, image_np = cap.read()

    # Expand dimensions since the model expects images to have shape: [1, None, None, 3]
    image_np_expanded = np.expand_dims(image_np, axis=0)

    # Things to try:
    # Flip horizontally
    # image_np = np.fliplr(image_np).copy()

    # Convert image to grayscale
    # image_np = np.tile(
    #     np.mean(image_np, 2, keepdims=True), (1, 1, 3)).astype(np.uint8)

    input_tensor = tf.convert_to_tensor(np.expand_dims(image_np, 0), dtype=tf.float32)
    detections, predictions_dict, shapes = detect_fn(input_tensor)

    label_id_offset = 1
    image_np_with_detections = image_np.copy()

    viz_utils.visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array(
          image_np_with_detections,
          detections['detection_boxes'][0].numpy(),
          (detections['detection_classes'][0].numpy() + label_id_offset).astype(int),
          detections['detection_scores'][0].numpy(),
          category_index,
          use_normalized_coordinates=True,
          max_boxes_to_draw=200,
          min_score_thresh=.30,
          agnostic_mode=False)

    # Display output
    cv2.imshow('object detection', cv2.resize(image_np_with_detections, (800, 600)))

    if variable_name_class == 'cat':
        {action 1}
    elif variable_name_class == 'dog':
        {action 2}

    if cv2.waitKey(25) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I don't know the 'variable_name_class' ..
anyone know how to get the classes name? or the 'variable_name_class' please help me..

Comment: In order to get the class name, you have to modify `viz_utils.visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array()`

Comment: @PrakashDahal can you help me? to get the 'variable_name_class'? please help me, there is a full code,I really appreciate it.. I'm stuck, I have try many tutorial but there no solution..

Answer (score 0):

Copy and paste the whole code from this link to your jupyter notebook cell:
https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/utils/visualization_utils.py

**You should copy all those 1500 lines of code.**

After copying all the code to jupyter notebook cell, you need to change some part of the code. Our aim is to return the detected label along with `image` array inside the `visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array()` function

So, part of the code for `visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array()` function should look like below code:

Update the code for `visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array()` function which should look like below.

```py
def visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array(
    image,
    boxes,
    classes,
    scores,
    category_index,
    instance_masks=None,
    instance_boundaries=None,
    keypoints=None,
    keypoint_scores=None,
    keypoint_edges=None,
    track_ids=None,
    use_normalized_coordinates=False,
    max_boxes_to_draw=20,
    min_score_thresh=.5,
    agnostic_mode=False,
    line_thickness=4,
    mask_alpha=.4,
    groundtruth_box_visualization_color='black',
    skip_boxes=False,
    skip_scores=False,
    skip_labels=False,
    skip_track_ids=False):
  """Overlay labeled boxes on an image with formatted scores and label names.
  This function groups boxes that correspond to the same location
  and creates a display string for each detection and overlays these
  on the image. Note that this function modifies the image in place, and returns
  that same image.
  Args:
    image: uint8 numpy array with shape (img_height, img_width, 3)
    boxes: a numpy array of shape [N, 4]
    classes: a numpy array of shape [N]. Note that class indices are 1-based,
      and match the keys in the label map.
    scores: a numpy array of shape [N] or None.  If scores=None, then
      this function assumes that the boxes to be plotted are groundtruth
      boxes and plot all boxes as black with no classes or scores.
    category_index: a dict containing category dictionaries (each holding
      category index `id` and category name `name`) keyed by category indices.
    instance_masks: a uint8 numpy array of shape [N, image_height, image_width],
      can be None.
    instance_boundaries: a numpy array of shape [N, image_height, image_width]
      with values ranging between 0 and 1, can be None.
    keypoints: a numpy array of shape [N, num_keypoints, 2], can
      be None.
    keypoint_scores: a numpy array of shape [N, num_keypoints], can be None.
    keypoint_edges: A list of tuples with keypoint indices that specify which
      keypoints should be connected by an edge, e.g. [(0, 1), (2, 4)] draws
      edges from keypoint 0 to 1 and from keypoint 2 to 4.
    track_ids: a numpy array of shape [N] with unique track ids. If provided,
      color-coding of boxes will be determined by these ids, and not the class
      indices.
    use_normalized_coordinates: whether boxes is to be interpreted as
      normalized coordinates or not.
    max_boxes_to_draw: maximum number of boxes to visualize.  If None, draw
      all boxes.
    min_score_thresh: minimum score threshold for a box or keypoint to be
      visualized.
    agnostic_mode: boolean (default: False) controlling whether to evaluate in
      class-agnostic mode or not.  This mode will display scores but ignore
      classes.
    line_thickness: integer (default: 4) controlling line width of the boxes.
    mask_alpha: transparency value between 0 and 1 (default: 0.4).
    groundtruth_box_visualization_color: box color for visualizing groundtruth
      boxes
    skip_boxes: whether to skip the drawing of bounding boxes.
    skip_scores: whether to skip score when drawing a single detection
    skip_labels: whether to skip label when drawing a single detection
    skip_track_ids: whether to skip track id when drawing a single detection
  Returns:
    uint8 numpy array with shape (img_height, img_width, 3) with overlaid boxes.
  """
  # Create a display string (and color) for every box location, group any boxes
  # that correspond to the same location.
  box_to_display_str_map = collections.defaultdict(list)
  box_to_color_map = collections.defaultdict(str)
  box_to_instance_masks_map = {}
  box_to_instance_boundaries_map = {}
  box_to_keypoints_map = collections.defaultdict(list)
  box_to_keypoint_scores_map = collections.defaultdict(list)
  box_to_track_ids_map = {}
  if not max_boxes_to_draw:
    max_boxes_to_draw = boxes.shape[0]
  for i in range(boxes.shape[0]):
    if max_boxes_to_draw == len(box_to_color_map):
      break
    if scores is None or scores[i] > min_score_thresh:
      box = tuple(boxes[i].tolist())
      if instance_masks is not None:
        box_to_instance_masks_map[box] = instance_masks[i]
      if instance_boundaries is not None:
        box_to_instance_boundaries_map[box] = instance_boundaries[i]
      if keypoints is not None:
        box_to_keypoints_map[box].extend(keypoints[i])
      if keypoint_scores is not None:
        box_to_keypoint_scores_map[box].extend(keypoint_scores[i])
      if track_ids is not None:
        box_to_track_ids_map[box] = track_ids[i]
      if scores is None:
        box_to_color_map[box] = groundtruth_box_visualization_color
      else:
        display_str = ''
        if not skip_labels:
          if not agnostic_mode:
            if classes[i] in six.viewkeys(category_index):
              class_name = category_index[classes[i]]['name']
            else:
              class_name = 'N/A'
            display_str = str(class_name)
            
        final_label = display_str
        if not skip_scores:
          if not display_str:
            display_str = '{}%'.format(round(100*scores[i]))
            final_label = display_str
          else:
            display_str = '{}: {}%'.format(display_str, round(100*scores[i]))
        if not skip_track_ids and track_ids is not None:
          if not display_str:
            display_str = 'ID {}'.format(track_ids[i])
            final_label = track_ids[i]
          else:
            display_str = '{}: ID {}'.format(display_str, track_ids[i])
        
        box_to_display_str_map[box].append(display_str)
        if agnostic_mode:
          box_to_color_map[box] = 'DarkOrange'
        elif track_ids is not None:
          prime_multipler = _get_multiplier_for_color_randomness()
          box_to_color_map[box] = STANDARD_COLORS[
              (prime_multipler * track_ids[i]) % len(STANDARD_COLORS)]
        else:
          box_to_color_map[box] = STANDARD_COLORS[
              classes[i] % len(STANDARD_COLORS)]

  # Draw all boxes onto image.
  for box, color in box_to_color_map.items():
    ymin, xmin, ymax, xmax = box
    if instance_masks is not None:
      draw_mask_on_image_array(
          image,
          box_to_instance_masks_map[box],
          color=color,
          alpha=mask_alpha
      )
    if instance_boundaries is not None:
      draw_mask_on_image_array(
          image,
          box_to_instance_boundaries_map[box],
          color='red',
          alpha=1.0
      )
    draw_bounding_box_on_image_array(
        image,
        ymin,
        xmin,
        ymax,
        xmax,
        color=color,
        thickness=0 if skip_boxes else line_thickness,
        display_str_list=box_to_display_str_map[box],
        use_normalized_coordinates=use_normalized_coordinates)
    if keypoints is not None:
      keypoint_scores_for_box = None
      if box_to_keypoint_scores_map:
        keypoint_scores_for_box = box_to_keypoint_scores_map[box]
      draw_keypoints_on_image_array(
          image,
          box_to_keypoints_map[box],
          keypoint_scores_for_box,
          min_score_thresh=min_score_thresh,
          color=color,
          radius=line_thickness / 2,
          use_normalized_coordinates=use_normalized_coordinates,
          keypoint_edges=keypoint_edges,
          keypoint_edge_color=color,
          keypoint_edge_width=line_thickness // 2)

  return final_label, image
```

Here, I have just created a variable called `final_label` which is the class name of the detected bounding box.

While calling this function, you have to use this code:

```py
label, _ = visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array(
            image_np_with_detections, #change this according to your image array name
            detections['detection_boxes'],
            detections['detection_classes']+label_id_offset,
            detections['detection_scores'],
            category_index,
            use_normalized_coordinates=True,
            max_boxes_to_draw=8,
            min_score_thresh=.50,
            agnostic_mode=False)

print(label)
```

It will give the exact label detected.

Answer (score 0):

Though, it's been some time, since this question was posted, if someone still want's to get the class-names without changing the code (as suggested above), one can post these two lines after getting visualization on the image.

```
classes = [cls for cls in detections['detection_classes'][detections['detection_scores'] > threshold]]
classes = [category_index.get(cls)['name'] for cls in classes]
```